# How to write an Excel file to memory?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am writing a set of records in excel but I am not supposed to create a physical file. How do I write the records in excel in memory? If I do write it, how do I see the output of the records?
I have tried:

```
import xlsxwriter
import io

filename= io.BytesIO()
workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename,{'in_memory': True})
worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet('sheet1')
worksheet.write(1,1,'Testing')
print(workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('sheet1'))
workbook.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have (as far as writing the file to memory goes)? BTW, I think `filename` should be a string (and from the documentation it doesn't sound like you need to be using `io.BytesIO` anyway).

Comment: The issue i am facing is that i was able to write the contents from a database to an excel file, but i was told not to write t Ao a physical disk. I tried with io.stringIO() but no luck. The excel workbook has 10 sheets and i have to pipe it as a stream Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: After looking at the xlsxwriter source code, I don't think you can do what you want—it depends on being given the name of file. Using `'in_memory'` prevents it from creating any temp files, but ultimately it needs the name of file that it can open (by name) and write data into.

Comment: Thank you Martineau. Yes your are right. I tweaked the code to look as follows and i was able to write in memory.  

with open("demo.xlsx", 'wb') as out:  ## Open temporary file as bytes
            out.write(output.getvalue())

As mentioned by you, i had to supply a file name.

Comment: That means you are creating a (temporary) physical file.

Comment: That line was to check whether i am able to write to memory or not.
The actual code is:
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})

The above code wrote the xlsx file into memory

Comment: I am trying to read a streamed xlsx file. The user inputs the data via user interface and then the data is passed to me via streaming in xlsx. How do i read it ? I couldn't find any documentation.
cat text.xlsx | python myprogram.py
How do i read this stream ? Any help would be appreciated. I am not sure whether openpyxl allows this read. I am using python3

Comment: If you are on a linux system, you could make a temporary filesystem in RAM using the methods found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188536/how-to-make-a-temporary-file-in-ram) and write your file into it. This is probably overkill for you application though.

Comment: you could create a memory disk

Answer (score 2):

From the XlsxWriter [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html):

> It is possible to write files to in-memory strings using BytesIO as follows:

```py
    from io import BytesIO

    output = BytesIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')
    workbook.close()


    xlsx_data = output.getvalue()
```

> To avoid the use of any temporary files and keep the entire file in-memory use the in_memory constructor option shown above.
>
> See also [Example: Simple HTTP Server](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_http_server.html#ex-http-server).

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay for you to use `xlwt` (seems to only work with *old* .xls files), you can try something like this:

```
import io
from xlwt import Workbook

file_excel = io.BytesIO()
workbook = Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('sheet1')

sheet.write(0, 0, 'column1')
sheet.write(0, 1, 'column2')
sheet.write(0, 2, 'column3')

sheet.write(1, 0, 'Field11')
sheet.write(1, 1, 'Field2')
sheet.write(1, 2, 'Field3')

workbook.save(file_excel)

data = file_excel.getvalue()
```

Source: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/6932/xlwt.Workbook.